# Angular - Problem with an Function Observable<number>

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Im doing the typescript code for a component. In this class typescript I did a function will return a number that represents a lenght from an array. I need this function works like an Observable. But i get this error "number is not assignable to type Observable"

```
  NumItemsCart():Observable<number>{
    let string_items = '';
    let array_temp = [];
    let num_items=0;
    
    string_items = localStorage.getItem('ecmm_list_shopcart');

    array_temp= cadena_items.split(',')
    
    num_items= array_temp.length -1

    return num_items
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's because the expected return type (`Observable<number>`) does not match your actual return type (`number`).
The easiest way to return a value as an observable is to use the `of()` function of RxJS (see docs [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of))

So with a little bit of simplification, your final code should look something like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

NumItemsCart(): Observable<number> {
    let string_items = '';
    let array_temp = [];

    string_items = localStorage.getItem('ecmm_list_shopcart');

    array_temp= cadena_items.split(',')

    return of(array_temp.length - 1)
}


const itemsLength: Observable<number> = NumItemsCart()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is pretty straightforward `NumItemsCart` method suppose to return `Observable` of number but its returning plain number.

All you need to make `num_items` as `Observable` by using rxjs [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) operator.

```
return of(num_items);
```